# Can Flash CS5.5 for iOS support features like Bluetooth for multiplayer and in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm looking to get into iOS development, and I'd much rather use the flash platform than Apple's Xcode (since Flash is able to compile for android etc.) However, I can't find info on  using iOS features like Bluetooth for multiplayer or in-app purchases, which is something of a deal breaker for me. So, is there any way to implement these in flash? I only really need to know if it's possible at this point, not how to do it.

Thanks in advance.